# Fail to implement layer normalization with keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras

I am trying to implement the [layer normalization](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.06450v1.pdf) in a fully connected neural network with keras. The issue I have met is that all the loss are `NaN` and it doesn't learn. Here is my code:

```
class DenseLN(Layer):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, init='glorot_uniform', activation='linear', weights=None,
                 W_regularizer=None, b_regularizer=None, activity_regularizer=None,
                 W_constraint=None, b_constraint=None, bias=True, input_dim=None, **kwargs):
        self.init = initializations.get(init)
        self.activation = activations.get(activation)
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.input_dim = input_dim
        self.epsilon = 1e-5        

        self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
        self.b_regularizer = regularizers.get(b_regularizer)
        self.activity_regularizer = regularizers.get(activity_regularizer)

        self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
        self.b_constraint = constraints.get(b_constraint)

        self.bias = bias
        self.initial_weights = weights
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(ndim=2)]

        if self.input_dim:
            kwargs['input_shape'] = (self.input_dim,)
        super(DenseLN, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def ln(self, x):
        # layer normalization function
        m = K.mean(x, axis=0)
        std = K.sqrt(K.var(x, axis=0) + self.epsilon)
        x_normed = (x - m) / (std + self.epsilon)
        x_normed = self.gamma * x_normed + self.beta
        return x_normed

    def build(self, input_shape):
        assert len(input_shape) == 2
        input_dim = input_shape[1]
        self.input_spec = [InputSpec(dtype=K.floatx(),
                                     shape=(None, input_dim))]

        self.gamma = K.variable(np.ones(self.output_dim) * 0.2, name='{}_gamma'.format(self.name)) 
        self.beta = K.zeros((self.output_dim,), name='{}_beta'.format(self.name))

        self.W = self.init((input_dim, self.output_dim),
                           name='{}_W'.format(self.name))
        if self.bias:
            self.b = K.zeros((self.output_dim,),
                             name='{}_b'.format(self.name))
            self.trainable_weights = [self.W, self.gamma, self.beta, self.b]
        else:
            self.trainable_weights = [self.W, self.gamma, self.beta]
        self.regularizers = []
        if self.W_regularizer:
            self.W_regularizer.set_param(self.W)
            self.regularizers.append(self.W_regularizer)

        if self.bias and self.b_regularizer:
            self.b_regularizer.set_param(self.b)
            self.regularizers.append(self.b_regularizer)

        if self.activity_regularizer:
            self.activity_regularizer.set_layer(self)
            self.regularizers.append(self.activity_regularizer)

        self.constraints = {}
        if self.W_constraint:
            self.constraints[self.W] = self.W_constraint
        if self.bias and self.b_constraint:
            self.constraints[self.b] = self.b_constraint

        if self.initial_weights is not None:
            self.set_weights(self.initial_weights)
            del self.initial_weights

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        output = K.dot(x, self.W)
        output = self.ln(output)
        #print (theano.tensor.shape(output))
        if self.bias:
            output += self.b
        return self.activation(output)

    def get_output_shape_for(self, input_shape):
        assert input_shape and len(input_shape) == 2
        return (input_shape[0], self.output_dim)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, activation='sigmoid', input_dim=12))
model.add(DenseLN(98, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(DenseLN(108, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(DenseLN(1))
adadelta = Adadelta(lr=0.1, rho=0.95, epsilon=1e-08)
adagrad = Adagrad(lr=0.003, epsilon=1e-08)

model.compile(loss='poisson',
              optimizer=adagrad,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train_scale,
          Y_train,
          batch_size=3000,
          callbacks=[history],
          nb_epoch=300)
```

Do you know what's wrong here and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I have also tried some combinations of the layers and found something weired. If the input and output layer are both normal `Dense` layer, the accuracy would be very low, nearly zero. But if the input layer is `DenseLN`, i.e., my customized layer, the accuracy would be `0.6+` at first and after tens of iterations, it reduced to zero again. Indeed I copied most of the code from `Dense` layer and all the difference is the `ln` function and `self.ln(output)` in `call` function. Besides, I have also added the `gamma` and `beta` to the `trainable_weights`.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The problem is the objective.... It is fixed when I change it to `binary-entropy`

Comment: I would suggest you implement this as a separate operations from the dense layer, similar to how batch normalization layer is typically implemented. It will also make the whole code much simpler as then this layer won't have any parameters. I suggest you give a look at how BatchNorm is implemented in Keras: https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/normalization.py

Answer (score 2):

It's a lot cleaner and more flexible if you implement it as a separate layer. Something like this should work:

```
class LayerNorm(Layer):
    """ Layer Normalization in the style of https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.06450 """
    def __init__(self, scale_initializer='ones', bias_initializer='zeros', **kwargs):
        super(LayerNorm, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.epsilon = 1e-6
        self.scale_initializer = initializers.get(scale_initializer)
        self.bias_initializer = initializers.get(bias_initializer)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.scale = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],), 
                                     initializer=self.scale_initializer,
                                     trainable=True,
                                     name='{}_scale'.format(self.name))
        self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1],),
                                    initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                    trainable=True,
                                    name='{}_bias'.format(self.name))
        self.built = True

    def call(self, x, mask=None):
        mean = K.mean(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        std = K.std(x, axis=-1, keepdims=True)
        norm = (x - mean) * (1/(std + self.epsilon))
        return norm * self.scale + self.bias

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return input_shape
```